# crnk-client doesn't load related resources

Tags: java, json-api, crnk

I'm using `crnk-client 2.6` to load JSON API resources.

Here is a simplified situation. I have two resources and want to fetch `Leads` data with `Contacts` info, however `contact` field with `@JsonApiRelation` annotation contains `null`. Here is this debug session:

[image]

How to populate `contact` field without an additional request?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something missing on the backend side. Does the leads repository populate contact? If not, JsonApiRelation.lookupBehavior must be setup. And JsonApiRelation annotation be used or a custom relationship repository implemented.

You may also verify the request in a browser to check the server response an exclude the client as source of the problem, but here rather unlikely.